# REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE takes not all the fields

Tags: abap

I have a problem with REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE FM. I need to add 5 fields into ALV.

```
DATA: BEGIN OF gt_collective7 OCCURS 0,
    selected(1),
    dat LIKE resb-bdter,
    overdue TYPE c,
    werks   LIKE resb-werks,
    extwg   LIKE mara-extwg,
    vd      LIKE fmfincode-fincode,
 ...
      TM like afvc-tplnr,
      ARBPL_Z like pat106-entries,
      ARBPL_R like pat106-entries,
      PLTXT like iflo-pltxt,
      lgort like resb-lgort,
  END OF gt_collective7,
```

gt_collective7 defined. Next i use

```
CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
    EXPORTING
      i_program_name         = sy-repid
      i_internal_tabname     = 'GT_COLLECTIVE7'
      i_inclname             = sy-repid
      i_bypassing_buffer     = 'X'
    CHANGING
      ct_fieldcat            = fieldcat
    EXCEPTIONS
      inconsistent_interface = 1
      program_error          = 2
      OTHERS                 = 3.
```

and inside fieldcat there's no new fields appear. What could be a problem in this case? I thought that it could be 'type' inside gt_collective7 definition, but no - it worked just fine previously.

Comment: Is there any special reason for using an obsolete way to declare the data structure?

Comment: Works for me. Anything special about the rest of the fields?

Comment: Works for me too. What error does it show?

Comment: Maybe not the answer but an alternative, is it ok if I recommend you to use 'CL_SALV_TABLE'?

Comment: 1. No, there's no special reason - it's just existed this way long before me. The only modification i need to do - to add the last 5 fields to the structure.
2. It doesn't show any errors. But no trace of 5 last fields either. 
3. Uhm, may be. But CL_SALV_TABLE would require rewriting whole module. I'll look into it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how exactly that helped, but declaring all additional fields of gt_collective7 in lowercase and reactivating the program somehow resolved situation.